# C++ Templates as arguments for templates

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, template-templates

I ran into the following problem. I have the following template `Number`:

```
template<int n>
struct Number
{
    static const int value = n;
};
```

Suppose now that I want to add two such Numbers at compile time. Specifically, I want to get the following snippet to work:

```
//The following code should display 7:
std::cout << Number_add< Number<3>, Number<4> >::value << std::endl;
```

I tried something like this, but my compiler doesn't like it.

```
template<Number<int> n1, Number<int> n2>
struct Number_add
{
    static const int value = n1::value + n2::value;
}
```

What is the correct way to implement Number_add? I think that template template parameters might be needed here, but I couldn't get that to work either. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `template<class n1, class n2> struct Number_add`

Comment: Ah, it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Number<int>` cannot be used as a [non-type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) because User defined classes aren't one of the allowed types. The allowed types are (reproduced from [*cppreference.com*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter)):

> - std::nullptr_t (since C++11);
> - integral type;
> - lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
> - pointer type (to object or to function);
> - pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
> - enumeration type.

---

You can simply do as `n.m` suggested in the comments

```
template<typename n1, typename n2>
struct Number_add
{
    static const int value = n1::value + n2::value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<int A, int B>
constexpr Number<A+B>
operator+(Number<A>, Number<B> ){ return {}; }

template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
using Number_add=decltype(Lhs{}+Rhs{});

std::cout << Number_add< Number<3>, Number<4> >::value << std::end;
```

Prints 7.